# How to import Secret in airflow?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-secrets

I was trying to use a module in airflow called Secrets to pass secrets to KubernetesOperator in Airflow.
It should be imported as `from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.secret import Secret`

But I'm getting an error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.contrib.kubernetes'`

I have tried to install apache-airflow kubernetes package `pip install apache-airflow[kubernetes]`
but this did not help.

Comment: Where are you calling `from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.secret import Secret` from?

Comment: from the python script

Comment: What version of airflow are u using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import is:

```
from airflow.kubernetes.secret import Secret
```

Note that the Secret class in Airflow can only **reference** secrets already exist in Kubernetes.

If you are looking to "pass" = generate secrets then it won't work. You first must create them in Kubernetes. You can do this by using `create_namespaced_secret` of the Kubernetes Python SDK - see [Using create_namespaced_secret API in Kubernetes Python client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405562/using-create-namespaced-secret-api-in-kubernetes-python-client)

Noting that there is [open feature request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28086) to be able to use credentials passed from Airflow Connections to the POD running the workload.

Answer (score 0):

The import depends on Airflow version.

**Airflow 1.x**

```
from airflow.kubernetes.secret import Secret
```

Example in documentation for [Airflow 1.10.15](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/kubernetes.html)

**Airflow 2.x**

```
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.secret import Secret
```

Example in documentation for [Airflow 2.7.3](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_modules/tests/system/providers/cncf/kubernetes/example_kubernetes.html)